# How to get the arguments for opening file with electron app

Tags: electron

Perhaps I'm being stupid but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get the startup arguments for an electron app. My scenario is something like this:

- Right-click file in Windows Explorer
- Open with -> My electron app
- Electron app opens and can work with the file

I can get the electron app to open, but how do I work with the file that was right-clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have the "Open with" portion working, Windows will pass the filename as a command line argument. So just get the file name/path from `process.argv`

```js
if(process.argv.length >= 2) {
    let filePath = process.argv[1];
    //open, read, handle file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        var electron = require('electron');
        var app = electron.remote;
        if (app.process.platform == 'win32' && app.process.argv.length >= 2) {
            var openFilePath = app.process.argv[1];
            if (openFilePath !== "") {
                console.log(openFilePath);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
```