# How can I get information about the file that launched my app?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

Similar to [How to get the arguments for opening file with electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828843/how-to-get-the-arguments-for-opening-file-with-electron-app) but the solution there is not working for me.

Using:
OS - Windows 10
Electron - https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases.git#v1.8.7-vmp1010
electron-builde -  v20.28.3

I have a an electron app build with electron-builder, and using the latter I have specified a custom file association, `.custom`.

So when you double-click on a file with this extension, `file.custom`, the installed app opens. This file would have some data in it that the app needs, and I'd like to read this data using my app.

Is there any way that my app can detect what launched it, so that I can say `"file.custom" launched me, and it's sitting at "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\`,?

The file does not appear in `process.argv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the file using process.argv, example:

```
var ipc = require('ipc');
var fs = require('fs');

// read the file and send data to the render process
ipc.on('get-file-data', function(event) {
    var data = null;
    if (process.platform == 'win32' && process.argv.length >= 2) {
        var openFilePath = process.argv[1];
        data = fs.readFileSync(openFilePath, 'utf-8');
    }
    event.returnValue = data;
});
```

source: [Source](https://blog.theodo.fr/2015/12/link-files-to-application-in-windows/)

Comment: This seems to be a little outdated. What is 'ipc'? Also, I don't see the file that opened my app in the process.argv array.

Comment: IPC is used to communicate between Electron BrowserWindows (rather the renderer.js) and the main.js. https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main
I don't think this solution is outdated yet, I couldn't find any other way to do it. But I am no expert tho

Comment: I say it's outdated because `var ipc = require('ipc')` has evidently been changed to `const {ipcMain} = require('electron').icpMain` since 2015.

Besides that, is `ipc`/`ipcMain` really necessary here if all I would need to do is read `process.argv[1]` if my objective is to get information about the file that launched my app?

Comment: I don't think you need IPC at all, it's just used to trigger the event. The way IPC is used may be outdated, but I don't think process.argv is outdated, since it is still part of the node.js documentation: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv