# Get the filepath which open with electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I am building a text editor with electron, and I want to open files with my text editor, lik some file open with my editor or double click to open file, 
I fixed it for windows using process.argv because when some file open with electron it save thr path of file in command line arguments process.argv,
But the same thing is not working for linux or mac, so could some one help me to get this working for linux or mac.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add file associations to your project / Windows: [Node File Associations](https://blog.theodo.fr/2015/12/link-files-to-application-in-windows/)

Then, you can access it with process.argv[1](https://blog.theodo.fr/2015/12/link-files-to-application-in-windows/) in your main.js.

Maybe this can help you: [Electron process.argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194506/how-can-i-get-information-about-the-file-that-launched-my-app/52202606?noredirect=1#comment91375377_52202606)

Comment: This is working for windows, i want to get this work for linux